# Elevation not working in Toolbar when a logo is used

Tags: java, android, toolbar, elevation, android-elevation

The **elevation** of my **toolbar** is not working when I use a **Logo**.

**XML** of my toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarPrincipal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/Cor_toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    android:elevation="5dp"/>
```

[toolbar with Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcEjy.png)

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarPrincipal);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.toolbar_logo);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

But when I don't use a Logo it apears

```
//Configuração da Toolbar
    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarPrincipal);
    toolbar.setTitle("Editar Perfil");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

[toolbar without Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgiuX.png)

Comment: What happens if you set the title to be a space? `toolbar.setTitle(" ")`?

Comment: Nothing happens continues the same